# remove items from array with the same id one by one

Tags: javascript, ember.js

the problem is that I have multiple objects with the same id. As you can see this works when it comes to removing all the items with the same id. How I can remove the objects one by one no matter if they are the same ID...thanks

```
individualObjects:[],
actions:{
   increment:function(){
      var obj = this.get('object');
      this.get('individualObjects').pushObject(obj);
   },
   decrement:function(){
      var obj = this.get('object');
      var filter = this.get('individualObjects').findBy('obj_id', obj.get('obj_id'));
      this.get('individualObjects').removeObject(filter);
   }
}
```

Comment: Is requirement for an `ember.js` solution ? Can you include original array and expected result at Question ?

Comment: my problem is that some of the objects have the same Id. If use filterBy will work but will remove all the items with the same id. What I want is to be able to remove one object at the time even if the are the same id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to filter array you would need to use Array.filter to find out the items that do not belong in the "*individualObjects*" and later simply remove them by using "*removeObjects*"

```
decrement:function(){
          var objects = this.get('individualObjects')
          var notWanted = objects.filterBy('obj_id', this.get('object.obj_id')); 
          this.get('individualObjects').removeObjects(notWanted);
}
```

and solution 2

```
decrement:function(){
      var removeObj = this.get('object');
      var objects = this.get('individualObjects')
      // As the condition is true given object is returned
      var notWanted = objects.filter(obj => { return obj.get('obj_id') === removeObj.get('obj_id')  }); 
      this.get('individualObjects').removeObjects(notWanted);
}
```

Ok so you want to remove items one by one. Weird but can be accomplished

first get the length for

```
var notWantedCount = objects.filterBy('obj_id', this.get('object.obj_id')).length;
```

Now

```
for(var i=0; i <= notWantedCount; i++) {
   var toRemove = individualObjects.findBy('obj_id', obj.get('obj_id'));
   individualObjects.removeObject(toRemove);
   // Make some custom actions one by one.
}
```

Comment: thanks but I need to removeObject even if they are the same id

Comment: @JosephCC Any time (Y)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ember, but you'll want to do a foreach on the array, and then test for id on each one. It should be something like this:

```
decrement:function(){
  var obj = this.get('object');
  self = this;
  this.get('individualObjects').each(function(individualObject) {
    if (individualObject.get('obj_id') == obj.get('obj_id'))

      ... you want to do something here? ...

      self.get('individualObjects').removeObject(individualObject);
  }
}
```

That way you can remove each object individually. Running any necessary code before or after it's removed. If you want to sort it first, you can do that before running the each function.

Comment: so this will not work for my case since some of the objects will have the same id. Even if they have the same ID I want to be able to remove one by one... Thanks anyways I ll kepp trying